# Exec function in c is not running

Tags: c, operating-system, exec

This is not running on my Mac for some reasons that I can't figure out. the output I am getting is only from the main.c 
the output is

```
Parent PID 4066
Child PID 4067
Process 4067 exited with status 5
```

I need the main.c to execute counter.c and pass the argument 5 which I will then have to use it inside the for a loop, but I can't get exec to run at all no matter what path I put.

//main.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pid_t childOrZero = fork();

    if (childOrZero < 0){
        perror("Error happened while trying to fork\n");
        exit(-1);
    }


    if (childOrZero == 0){
        printf("Child PID %d\n", (int)getpid());
        execl("./counter", "5", NULL);
        exit(5);
    }

    // THis must be parent
    printf("Parent PID %d\n", (int)getpid());
    int status = 0;
    pid_t childpid = wait(&status);
    int childReturnedValue = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    printf("Process %d exited with status %d\n", (int)childOrZero, childReturnedValue);

    return 0;
}
```

counter.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        printf("Process: %d  %d\n", (int)getpid(),i);
        //sleep(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `perror()` or print `errno` after `execl` call.

Comment: No such file or directory. I tried using the absolute path and it is still not working

Comment: What is the precise way you compile counter.c? Can you execute it from the command line yourself after compiling it?

Comment: Please show your full log from compiling both programs to running the main program.

Comment: ⭕ p1$  gcc counter.c
⭕ p1$  ./a.out
Process: 4144  0
Process: 4144  1
Process: 4144  2
Process: 4144  3
Process: 4144  4

Comment: `a.out`?? So why are you running `counter` in your code?

Comment: before compiling this file run this command `cc counter.c -o counter`

Comment: @iali87: Avoid commenting your own question, instead **edit your question** to improve it (by giving more details, e.g. how did you compile `counter.c` and `main.c`). I recommend to compile the first with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g counter.c -o counter` and the second with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g main.c -o mymain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you mention you compile `counter.c` into an executable called `a.out`. This is the default executable name when you do not provide an output name explicitly to the compiler. Thus, if you compile both `counter.c` and `main.c`, only one of them will be the `a.out`.

You can provide `gcc` an option to name your executable different from the default:

`gcc -o counter counter.c`

Also, your invocation of `execl` is not quite correct. The first argument is the path to the executable, but the remaining arguments will become `argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, etc. Thus, you really want to invoke `execl` this way:

```
     execl("./counter", "counter", "5", NULL);
```

Comment: this can also be a comment :/

Comment: I know this and it still will give me a 'bad address' pereor message.

Comment: @iali87: There was a mistake in your invocation of `execl`.

Comment: @iali87: Regarding *I know this...*, I did ask you for the precise way you compiled `counter.c`, because I wanted to know if you had generated an executable with the correct name. Your answer to my question led me to conclude you had not.

Answer (score 0):

Read [documentation of `execl` for MacOSX](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/execl.3.html) and the [POSIX specification of `execl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html)

It can fail (and that is the only case when it is returning). So code:

```
if (childOrZero == 0){
    printf("Child PID %d\n", (int)getpid());
    execl("./counter", "5", NULL);
    perror("execl counter");
    exit(5);
}
```